# how can I update a table with multiple dropdown in PHP?

Tags: php

MY HTML

```
<div class="normal-text">
        <?  $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client")or die(mysql_error());
            while ($check2 = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
        {
            $checkgather = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gather where client_id = '".$check2['client_id']."' ")or die(mysql_error());
            $checkgather2 = mysql_fetch_array( $checkgather );
            echo  $check2['client_name'].' : 

                <select name="gather" class=\"form-field\">
                <option value="hashtag"  '.(($checkgather2['gather_choice']=='hashtag')?'selected="selected"':"").' >hashtag</option>
                <option value="latitude" '.(($checkgather2['gather_choice']=='latitude')?'selected="selected"':"").' >latitude/longitude</option>
                <option value="followers" '.(($checkgather2['gather_choice']=='followers')?'selected="selected"':"").'>followers</option>
                </select>   
            <a href="#" class="link-small">Start Thread to gather</a><br>';
        } 
        ?>
        <br>
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </div>
```

I have several rows of results.. each with a dropdown menu of what's in the DB...  If I change 1 or multiple values, and I press the UPDATE button... How can I treat the code..

I'm assuming I'll need a foreach(.... )

my current PHP is this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 { 
   $update = mysql_query("UPDATE gather set gather_choice = '  ' where client_id = '  ' ")or die(mysql_error());
 }
```

But I'll probably need a foreach somewhere...   Any tips on how to make this work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming you have a unique key on client_id

```
INSERT INTO gather (gather_choice, client_id)
VALUES (first_choice, first_client_id), (second_choice, second_client_id)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE client_id = VALUES(client_id)
```

This will basically try to insert first, but seeing that it already exists, will just update it.

Comment: and what do I use to get (first_choice, first_client_id).. I need to use an array.. .how to I pass the values from my HTML since there are multiple gather_choice and multiple_client_id...  If I add a hidden field for the client ID: `<input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="'.$check2['client_id'].'">`  I won't be able to retrieve it without an array...

Comment: each input needs it's own name. i would name them client_id[1], client_id[2], etc. that way PHP will actually give you an array in your $_POST variable.

Comment: sorry, you might want to make it gather[.$client_id.]